# Extend pandas DataFrame DatetimeIndex by 25 week days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have been trying to extend my Pandas DataFrame Date Index by 25 week days. The following test example that I wrote demonstrates the problem. Weekdays are being correctly generated, however, they are not being appended to the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
from business_calendar import Calendar

dates = pd.date_range('20190121', periods=5)
df = pd.DataFrame({'high': (58.22, 57.93, 57.51, 57.89, 58.77), 'low': (57.65, 57.15, 56.98, 57.12, 58.00)}, index=dates)

cal = Calendar()
last_idx = df.index[-1].date()
for i in range(1, 26):
    weekdays = pd.DatetimeIndex([cal.addbusdays(last_idx, i)])
    print("idx_count: {:2d} idx: {}".format(i, weekdays))
    df.index.append(weekdays)
print(df.index)
```

The code exits with errorlevel 0, any ideas why the DataFrame is not being updated as expected?

Comment: Can you append the index entries when you are not appending data to the DataFrame  ?

Comment: @w2kpro , so you are trying to extend the index by 25 days? and the values should be na right?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add rows to your Dataframe with weekdays as the index, so an easy way to do that would be

```
for i in range(1, 26):
   weekdays = pd.DatetimeIndex([cal.addbusdays(last_idx, i)])
   #If you want the values to be na
   newRow = pd.DataFrame(index=weekdays)
   #Or if you want to give values to the new rows
   newRow = pd.DataFrame({'high': (42), 'low': (0)}, index=weekdays)

   df = df.append(newRow)

del newRow
print(df.index)
```

---

Comment: Running the code without giving values works, but a warning is generated:  frame.py:6701: FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not ligned. A future version of pandas will change to not sort by default. To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'. To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'. sort=sort)

Comment: set the sort parameter to false : df = df.append(newRow,sort=False)

Comment: Yes, that suppresses the warning!

Answer (score 0):

Did some changes to the code *(explanation in comments)*:

```
import pandas as pd
from business_calendar import Calendar

dates = pd.date_range('20190121', periods=5)
df = pd.DataFrame({'high': (58.22, 57.93, 57.51, 57.89, 58.77), 'low': (57.65, 57.15, 56.98, 57.12, 58.00)}, index=dates)

cal = Calendar()
last_idx = df.index[-1].date()
idx_list=[] #added this line
for i in range(1, 26):
    weekdays = pd.DatetimeIndex([cal.addbusdays(last_idx, i)])
    #print(weekdays[0])
    idx_list.append(weekdays[0]) #appending just the value so weekdays[0]
idx_list.extend(df.index) #extend the list with index
df.reindex(idx_list).sort_index() #reindex the df and sort the index

            high    low
2019-01-21  58.22  57.65
2019-01-22  57.93  57.15
2019-01-23  57.51  56.98
2019-01-24  57.89  57.12
2019-01-25  58.77  58.00
2019-01-28    NaN    NaN
2019-01-29    NaN    NaN
2019-01-30    NaN    NaN
.......................
....................
....
```

Comment: Interesting. Is the second solution more efficient or is it just a different way to solve the same problem?

Comment: The above code is just a test fragment from an Ichimoku Clouds graph plotting program. Two of the moving averages have to be extended 26 periods into the future. So two columns of the DataFrame will have numerical values extending past the current date and the other values will be Nan.

Comment: @w2kpro i have not tested the other one, but dont see any reason why should not use your solution. So decided to just fix it instead of creating a new solution. :)